# Drop first element conditionally in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Trying to remove the first element of a list if it is zero (not really, but for the purpose of an example).

Given a list:

```
val ns = List(0, 1, 2)
```

Deleting the first zero could be done by dropping the first matches for zero:

```
List(0, 1, 2).dropWhile(_ == 0)
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

Or you could delete everything that's not a zero.

```
List(0, 1, 2).filter(_ > 0)
res2: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

The problem with these is when the list has multiple zeroes.  The previous solutions don't work, because they delete too many zeroes:

```
List(0, 0, 1, 2, 0).filter(_ > 0)
res3: List[Int] = List(1, 2)

List(0, 0, 1, 2, 0).dropWhile(_ == 0)
res4: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 0)
```

Is there an existing function for this?

Comment: @ashawley, you can test for emptiness `if (ns.nonEmpty && (ns.head == 0)) ...` or use `headOption` i.e. `if (ns.headOption == Some(0)) ...`.  But I still prefer your pattern matching approach.

Comment: I think that if...else is most efficient. but if you want to over complicate it and do it in a single expression you can do something like
`list.headOption.filter(_ != 0).fold(List.empty[Int])(List(_)):::list.tail`

Comment: The answers mostly seem to be ways to write this function (several slower, less clear and/or more complex than the OP's own variants). It's very clear the OP is quite capable of coding this. The actual question is "Is there an existing function for this?". The answer to that is "No"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also think pattern matching is the best option for readability and performance (I tested and the pattern matching code from OP actually performs better than simple `if ... else ...`.).

```
List(0, 0, 1, 2, 0) match { 
  case 0 :: xs => xs 
  case xs => xs
}
res10: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 2, 0)
```

And, no, there's no simple built in function for this.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to drop the first element conditionally, then as jwvh commented, an `if/else` comprehension is probably the simplest:

```
if (ns.nonEmpty && ns.head == 0) {
    ns.tail
} else {
    ns
}
```

You could then of course wrap this into a function.

You could look for a sequence of one zero, and drop it:

```
if (ns.startsWith(List(0))) {
  ns.drop(1)
} else {
  ns
}
```

Also known as returning the tail:

```
if (ns.startsWith(List(0))) {
  ns.tail
} else {
  ns
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A neat generalized solution would be explicitly add information to your elements.

Example:
  *How to drop by condition and limit the amount from left to right?*

```
List(0,0,0,1,2,2,3).zipWithIndex.dropWhile({case (elem,index) => elem == 0 && index < 2})
```

Result:

```
res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((0,2), (1,3), (2,4), (2,5), (3,6))
```

You can get your previous representation with:

```
res0.map.{_._1}
```

To do everything in N, you can use lazy evaluation + the `force` method.

```
List(0,0,0,1,2,2,3).view.zipWithIndex.dropWhile({case (elem,index) => elem == 0 && index < 2}).map {_._1}.force
```

This will basically do all the operations on your initial collection in one single iteration. See [scaladoc](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/views.html) for more info to Scala views..

Modifying your condition on the right size you can choose how far the drop condition will reach inside your collection.

Comment: Your "lazy" version is O(length-of-list) still. There's no need for this. It should be O(length-of-prefix-to--test).

Answer (score 1):

You can zip the list with an index:

```
ns.zipWithIndex.filter( x =>( x._1 != 0 || x._2 != 0)).map(_._1)
```

Here's a similar solution using `dropWhile`:

```
ns.zipWithIndex.dropWhile { 
  case (x, idx) => x == 0 && idx == 0
} map(_._1)
```

This could also be a for-comprehension

```
for {
  (x, idx) <- ns.zipWithIndex
  if (x != 0 || idx != 0) )
} yield {
  x
}
```

But as Paul mentioned, it will unnecessarily iterate over the entire list.

Comment: How is this an improvement on the OP's suggestions?

Comment: I think any solution using `zipWithIndex` merely to later test the index is zero is no improvement. Among other things, they iterate over the whole list (twice - once to add the index, once to remove it again) for an operation that should be constant-time.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul you can avoid this by using `view.zipWithIndex...force`.

Comment: No, you can't. The `force` will evaluate all but the first element (if removed) or all (if not removed) so that's still O(N). And with `view`, more overhead. The OP's requirement is to inspect the first element of the list and conditionally remove it. Any solution that pointlessly processes all other elements of the list is no improvement, IMO. The pattern-matching option is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generalised variant (drop up to K elements matching the predicate) which does not process the rest of the list

```
  def dropWhileLimit[A](xs: List[A], f: A => Boolean, k: Int): List[A] = {
    if (k <= 0 || xs.isEmpty || !f(xs.head)) xs
    else dropWhileLimit(xs.tail, f, k - 1)
  }
```

and some test cases:

```
dropWhileLimit(List(0,1,2,3,4), { x:Int => x == 0}, 1)
//> res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
dropWhileLimit(List(0,1,2,3,4), { x:Int => x == 0}, 2)
//> res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
dropWhileLimit(List(0,0,0,0,0), { x:Int => x == 0}, 1)
//> res2: List[Int] = List(0, 0, 0, 0)
dropWhileLimit(List(0,0,0,0,0), { x:Int => x == 0}, 3)
//> res3: List[Int] = List(0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a good option if you wanna drop the first element according to the filter but the value isn't in the first place.

```
def dropFirstElement( seq: Seq[Int], filterValue: Int ): Seq[Int] = {
  seq.headOption match {
    case None => seq
    case Some( `filterValue` ) => seq.tail
    case Some( value ) => value +: dropFirstElement( seq.tail, filterValue )
  }
}
```